# Recursion program doesn't work for big inputs

Tags: c++, recursion

I tried to write an answer to the question from this site - https://main2.edu.pl/c/kurs-podstaw-algorytmiki-druga-e/p/kro/

It's addition to lesson about recursion so I came up with a code that uses it. It should show **(a+1)^b modulo-10000 remainder**. Unfortunately, for small numbers my program works, but when it reaches bigger numbers it just... doesn't - for example:

a = 1

b = 4

output is **16**,  which is correct.

a = 2

b = 3

output is **27**,  which is correct.


a = 2

b = 100

it gives me output **-8495**, which is completely incorrect.

I tried searching for it, but I didn't find proper solution to my problem, 'cause I don't really know what happened. I was thinking that maybe it's because of too small data type but changing **int** to **long int**, didn't change anything.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int pot(int a, int b){
    if (b == 1)
        return a;
    if (b % 2 == 0) //test for even number
        return pot(a, b / 2) * pot(a, b / 2);
    else //make it even number
        return a * pot(a, b - 1);
}

main(){
    int a, b;
    int P;
    cin>>P;
    for(int i = 1; i<=P; i++){
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        cin>>a;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<endl<<(pot(a+1, b))%10000;
    }
}
```

Comment: `pot(3, 100)` is way too big for any standard integer data type. You have to find an algorithm to reduce the size of the intermediate results.

Comment: Depending on your platform, `int` and `long int` might be identical.

Comment: @mch: the output of `pot(a, b)` should be a number between `0` and `10000`, so even a 16-bit integer would suffice. The problem is of course what happens with intermediate values before the modulo-operation is applied.

Comment: @G.Sliepen no, `pot(a, b)` returns the big number, the modulo is in the last line of main.

Comment: @mch Ah, you're totally right.

Comment: You should perform a modulo after each multiplication. Besides, you could avoid recursion with a simple loop, and  with a loop even get a O(log n) efficiency

Comment: If you are interested in an efficient implementation, you can have a look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64094/searching-for-efficient-method-to-compute-an-bmod-p-for-large-numbers)

Comment: By calling `pot(a, b/2) * pot(a, b/2)`, you demolish all advantage of fast computation in log time by exploding the number of calls exponentially. In the end, you have linear time. I suggest you store the result of a single call of `pot(a, b/2)` in a variable and use that for the multiplication.

Comment: I confirmed your error.  I next retried your code using uint64_t.  This result was 20 digits, a strong indication that this also wrapped-around (uint's wrap, int's overslow).  If you are interested, you might try using  <gmpxx.h> and replace int's with mpz_class.  FYI - the fib of 300 has 63 digits, and the computation (on my old desktop) of fib(0) thru fib(300) takes < 10 ms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of taking the remainder only of the final result, you should take it every time `pot` returns a value.  The result should be correct, since you're just multiplying the results by things, and `(x*y) % m` should equal `((x % m) * (y % m)) % m` for positive `x`, `y`, and `m`.

Try this:

```
int pot(int a, int b){
    int r;
    if (b == 1)
        r = a;
    else if (b % 2 == 0) //test for even number
        r = pot(a, b / 2) * pot(a, b / 2);
    else //make it even number
        r = a * pot(a, b - 1);
    return r % 10000;
}
```

Also, you're replicating the computation of `pot(a, b / 2)` in the second case, which will slow it down tremendously.  You should change:

```
r = pot(a, b / 2) * pot(a, b / 2);
```

to:

```
r = pot(a, b / 2);
r *= r;
```

(And of course add curly braces.)  That should be much faster.

Update:  I just corrected my answer to include an `else` for the second case that was not present in the original code.  It was not needed in the original code, but was needed after my changes.

Comment: The question is about fixing the modulo computation. Obviously, a doubly-recursive function won't be efficient. Commenting on the performance on an answer about the modulo part seems misplaced.

Comment: i am trying your solution in visual studio but i am getting stack overflow error.Unhandled exception at 0x00E02879 in ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x002F2F98). occurred

Comment: @NileshSolanki Oh, I see the problem - there was no `else` in the original code, which didn't matter when it had a `return` but was needed when I changed it to an assignment.  I just updated my answer.  It should work now.  Thanks for letting me know there was a problem.